# Are animations on power point acceptable?

Tags: professionalism, internship

I am presenting a software project to two supervisors and a director. I have a short power point to go along with it, my question is what is and isn't acceptable for a "professional" power point?

Comment: I would recommend that you minimize "fluff" like animations and focus on the basic information in the PowerPoint. You can't read the room when making the presentation, so it's better to play it safe. Once you get more familiar with the expectations, you'll know if you should put in animations or videos.

Comment: What kind of animation are you thinking? Does it make the information you are presenting easier to understand (i.e. data changing over time) or does it serve no real purpose (words flying in and out, your typical "transitions")?

Comment: Don't worry so much about the power point graphics. Just do the basics as far as using the corporate template, etc. Spend the bulk of your time, instead, focusing on making compelling points, preparing for any and all questions, and understanding the needs/requirements of your small but important audience. If you're not experienced in presentations then some practice sessions with trusted colleagues/mentors is a good idea. All of these things are VASTLY more important than graphics.

Comment: @Joe: Efficient and effective information transfer from speaker to audience has little to do with culture.  Pointless animations and "transitions" distract and dissipate attention because that's how people work.  Culture only matters in what is acceptable to get away with politically, not what is effective.  One group may not think anything wrong with lots of gratuitous animations and transitions because they all do it, with others you're immediately branded a weenie, and others may even walk out.  However, none of them will learn the intended material well from your presentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with any presentation, always keep the audience in mind.  Never do something because it's "cool" or cutesey.  Do it only if you think it will aid in getting the information you are presenting across more accurately, more reliably, keep their attention better, etc.

That said 99.9% of all PowerPoint animations are time-wasting attention-dissipating annoyances.  Only use animation when there is real benefit in moving images.  For example, if you're presenting research on how a bat flaps its wings, showing a slow-motion animation of that, while pointing out features, may be quite useful.

Otherwise, animations like the next frame sliding in, then the next one rotating into place, then the next one squeezing in and expanding, or whatever, are great ways to sabotage a presentation.  Everyone will be thinking about the animation for the next few seconds at least.  You might as well say "Blah, blah, blah" for a little while.

Once the mind switches to a new topic (in this case the animation), it becomes free to wander to other topics.  Your audience may only be thinking about the animation for a few seconds, but it will take much longer to get them back on track and in sync with your presentation again.

Keeping attention with gimmicks like animation is a fallacy.  They may look engaged because they're actively looking at the screen, but they won't be engaged with the information you are trying to present.

To keep the audience engaged *in the right topic*, you have to keep stimulating them in that topic and not give their minds opportunities to wander.  Any distractions counter that.  A quick switch from one slide or picture to the next isn't a distraction, but a fancy animated fade-in is.

Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Workspace specific context aside, in general animations are reasonable when they help carry the information. Animations just to show off you know how to use animations are most likely ignored or considered additional fluff that is distracting.

That being said, there are environments where you can impress by your presentation-fu or where the focus is less on content and more on form. Say in a marketing function, you might need the skill to "wow" your clients by the presentation, if the product won't do that for you. Still, the animations will need to fit into your overall "shiny-slides"-concept.

So, the more artistic your audience, the more likely some animations that are not conveying information are received positively, the more factual your profession/audience the less likely (again unless they help carry the information).

Answer (score 0):

Transitions (animations on changing slides) have no place in a professional PowerPoint presentation.

Animations (animations within a slide) have limited uses in a professional PowerPoint presentation. They should be used thoughtfully and with purpose.

Animations are a tool for directing the audience's attention. They can be useful in showing how something changes over time, with pieces of the whole sliding in and out. An animation can help the audience keep track of what is moving out and what is moving in. Without an animation, the audience needs to have a mental model of what was there and compare/contrast it with what is currently there. You're all but guaranteed to lose some folks.

Animations should be kept to a minimum and should not be distracting.